# Delay introduced while presenting UIViewController

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, storyboard, segue

I am developing application in which I am presenting new `UIViewController` from another using `[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"newViewSegue" sender:self];`

In new `UIViewController` I am initialising my view elements and adding `UITableView` programmatically to it.

But when I call this `performSegueWithIdentifier` new `UIViewController` is displayed after some delay, I tried to put log in `viewDidLoad` of new `UIViewController` and before `[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"newViewSegue" sender:self];` statement both statements are executed immediately but view is displayed after some interval.

My `ViewDidLoad` method is as follow:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad{
sharedObject=[SingleToneClass sharedManager];

    selectedButtonTag=-1;

    initFlag=0;
    NSLog(@"End %@",[NSDate date]);
    backgroundView.backgroundColor=[self hexToUiColor:@"E7E7E7"];

    [mondayDateButton setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    //set colour for all 7days buttons

    [mondayDateButton.titleLabel setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:14]];
    //Set font for all days button

    [mondayButton setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
   //set title colour

    [mondayButton.titleLabel setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:12]];
    //set font

    //Changing image Color
    //Home Button
    [homeButton.titleLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:kFontAwesomeFamilyName size:40]];
    [homeButton setTitleColor:[self hexToUiColor:sharedObject.secondaryHexColorCode] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [homeButton setTitle:[NSString fontAwesomeIconStringForIconIdentifier:@"fa-home"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    //Back Button
    [backButton.titleLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:kFontAwesomeFamilyName size:27]];
    [backButton setTitleColor:[self hexToUiColor:sharedObject.secondaryHexColorCode] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [backButton setTitle:[NSString fontAwesomeIconStringForIconIdentifier:@"fa-chevron-left"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    //Next Week Button
    [nextWeek.titleLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:kFontAwesomeFamilyName size:20]];
    [nextWeek setTitleColor:[self hexToUiColor:sharedObject.secondaryHexColorCode] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [nextWeek setTitle:[NSString fontAwesomeIconStringForIconIdentifier:@"fa-chevron-right"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    //Previous Week Button
    [previousWeek.titleLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:kFontAwesomeFamilyName size:20]];
    [previousWeek setTitleColor:[self hexToUiColor:sharedObject.secondaryHexColorCode] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [previousWeek setTitle:[NSString fontAwesomeIconStringForIconIdentifier:@"fa-chevron-left"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    [separatorLineView setBackgroundColor:[self hexToUiColor:@"6D6D6D"]];
    [selectLabel setTextColor:[self hexToUiColor:@"6D6D6D"]];


    [selectLabel setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:13]];
    selectLabel.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",selectedTitle];
    sharedObject.bookADateTitle=selectedTitle;

    //make Buttons Rounded

    mondayDateButton.clipsToBounds = YES;
    mondayDateButton.layer.cornerRadius = mondayDateButton.frame.size.height/2;


    NSDate *currentDate;
    if (sharedObject.bookDateViewDate.length>0) {
        NSDateFormatter *dateFormat1 = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        [dateFormat1 setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];
        currentDate=[dateFormat1 dateFromString:sharedObject.bookDateViewDate];
    }
    else{
        currentDate=[NSDate date];
    }

    [self setDate:currentDate];

    [self setDateToLabel:currentDate]; //set formatted date 


//create and initialise UITableView
    static NSString *cellIdentifier=@"CustomHiddenViewCell";
    CustomHiddenViewCell *cell = (CustomHiddenViewCell *)[slotsTableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomHiddenViewCell" owner:self options:nil];
    cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];

    double heightOfTable=(self.view.frame.size.height-backgroundView.frame.size.height);

    //creating tableview1
    slotsTableView=[[UITableView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(self.view.frame.origin.x,self.view.frame.origin.y+backgroundView.frame.size.height,self.view.frame.size.width,heightOfTable)];
    slotsTableView.scrollEnabled=YES;
    slotsTableView.delegate=self;
    [slotsTableView flashScrollIndicators];
    slotsTableView.dataSource=self;
    slotsTableView.bounces=NO;
    slotsTableView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator=YES;
    slotsTableView.separatorStyle=UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone;
    [self.view addSubview:slotsTableView];

    //add swipe gesture
    UISwipeGestureRecognizer *leftSwipRecognizer;
    leftSwipRecognizer = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(SwipeRecognizer:)];
    [leftSwipRecognizer setDirection:(UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft)];
    [slotsTableView addGestureRecognizer:leftSwipRecognizer];

    UISwipeGestureRecognizer *rightSwipRecognizer;
    rightSwipRecognizer = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(SwipeRecognizer:)];
    [rightSwipRecognizer setDirection:(UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight)];
    [slotsTableView addGestureRecognizer:rightSwipRecognizer];

    [leftWeekRecognizer addTarget:self action:@selector(WeekSwipeRecognizer:)];
    [leftWeekRecognizer setDirection:(UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft)];

    [rightWeekRecognizer addTarget:self action:@selector(WeekSwipeRecognizer:)];
    [rightWeekRecognizer setDirection:(UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight)];
}
```

Can anyone tell me why this delay is introduced?

Answer (score 0):

May be your code is executing in other then main thread, move your code in main thread or use GCD like

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
    //Run UI Updates
});
```

Comment: You mean I should add my initialisation code from `viewDidLoad`to `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
    //Run UI Updates
});` like    `-(void){dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
    //Initialisation
});}`

Comment: Yes, you can do like that or your performSegueWithIdentifier method!

Comment: I tried to use your solution but still it is introducing delay

Comment: show your did load method and you code which is generating view programmatically

Comment: I have updated my question with `viewDidLoad` method please check

Comment: Is there any thing like if `UITableView` is having more data it takes time to load and due to which this delay is introduced?

Comment: I guess no because tableView only load visible rows, and one ting more you should remove your cell init code from did load because that on belong here. I would say you should comment all the code and debug part by part code if you find no success for knowing delay